# Connecting to a SQL database via unity script

Tags: c#, sql, unity-game-engine, sqlite

I am trying to retrieve to three integer values from a SQL database through the use of a unity c# script. Currently, I am unable to retrieve the values due to an error in my connection line. I have no idea what the problem is and this is my first time using c# in conjunction with SQL.

Below is the code I am currently using,

```
public class PositionUpdater : MonoBehaviour{

// Use this for initialization
public int Cordx;
public int Cordy;
void Start () {
    var RoomDB = new SqlConnection("Data Source=D:/Coursework 2, 2d ver/Assets/Plugins/Rooms Table.db");
    RoomDB.Open();
    SqlCommand CMD = new SqlCommand("select Dpos1, Dpos2, DRot1 from tblRoom where Roomx=@Cordx and Roomy=@Cordy", RoomDB);
    CMD.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Cordx", Cordx);
    CMD.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Cordy", Cordy);
    using(var reader = CMD.ExecuteReader()){
        int Positionx = Convert.ToInt32(reader["Dpos1"]);
        int Positiony = Convert.ToInt32(reader["Dpos2"]);
        int Rotation = Convert.ToInt32(reader["Dpos1"]);
        print(Positionx);
    }

}
```

}

Comment: Assets\\Plugins\\Rooms Table.db is not a standard sql connection string. What is the connection string of the Sql database you've set up?

Comment: This is all I have in terms of a connection string, my database is a very simple local database stored in the directory Assets\Plugins\Rooms Table.db. It is a simple 1 table database. I have never written a connection string such as this before and all tutorials I have found use database hosted on the internet.

Comment: what about using `Assets\Plugins\Rooms Table.db` than and remove the double `\\`? Also note that most file IO has to be done in either StreamingAssets, Resources or the persistent data path

Comment: How did you "create" your local database? Usually it goes something along the lines of installing Sqlserver Express (or something like that) and hosting it locally on your machine. The .db file isn't actually a database you can connect to, it's just a file.

Comment: My database was created via a python script, and I have had no trouble accessing data via other python scripts. Also when I remove the double slashes I get a compiler error.

Comment: so how does the compiler error look like?

Comment: The compiler error is: Unrecognized escape sequence [Assembly-CSharp]

Comment: can you try `/` also please add all relevant information to your question not here in the comments. With all I also mean exactly the compiler error including the line where this happens

Comment: I have done some more research and have made some progress, I have changed the connection string as to include the data source argument at the start, and this has changed the error message I receive. I now receive FormatException: Input string was not in the correct format. This error is received regardless of whether or not I use /, \ or \\.

Answer (score -1):

The reason it was not working was I was should be using Sqliteconnection. If anyone else is new to this stuff this was the tutorial I followed.https://ornithoptergames.com/how-to-set-up-sqlite-for-unity/